# AlarmManager setInexactRepeating not correct repeat after sleep app

Tags: android, alarmmanager

i want to create repeating service by alarm manager. if app is running in live time then it is correct running every one min. it in sleep mode to running every five min. why it is not running every one min in sleep mode?

```
public static final long NOTIFY_INTERVAL = 60000;
AlarmManager alarms = getAlarmMAnager();
alarms.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), NOTIFY_INTERVAL, recurringAlarm);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is very much expected and can happen due to **various reasons**

- [**Android Oreo has limitations**](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background.html) on running services in background, so you may face this on O devices
- [**Doze mode**](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html) on Android Marshmallow onwards can cause this, it will stop all network operations itself & take away CPU wake locks
- AlarmManager is not meant to for doing repeated operations in background

I will suggest you to use **[JobsSchedulers](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html)** or **[Firebase Dispatchers](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android)** for tasks which you want to execute in background, as it will take care of Doze mode, background service limitations, no network scenarios etc.

Comment: i cannot use this two methods. this app has internal network. cannot connect firebase service and give error FirebaseApp initialization unsuccessful. JobsSchedulers wants to min  sdk version is 21 but my project min sdk version 19.

Comment: Firebase Job dispatcher doesn't require you to use Firebase Services and it works API level 9+

Comment: but give an error   FirebaseApp initialization unsuccessful.why give this error?

Comment: firebse dispacther has a bug.  replaced Trigger.NOW with Trigger.executionWindow(0, 0). it is runnning correctly thanks.